# Modify Kubuntu cursor theme

Tags: kubuntu, kde, themes

I would like to personalize my cursor on Kubuntu 18.04 (KDE Plasma 5.12.7)
Since I don't want do it from scratch, I got files from Plasma Breeze theme (/usr/share/icons/breeze_cursors/) which is the default cursor.

I want to modify the "wait" and "progress" : when opening it with gimp, it is 69 layers (23 * 3 resolution). The 23 images are the animations of the cursor
I tried to modify it with the animation I want, save it on gimp as a GIF file, then remove the file extension and replace the original file with the new one (/usr/share/icons/breeze_cursors/cursors/wait)

However this did no works: even after restarting the computer, the cursor wasn't modified.

My package manager doesn't know ubuntu-tweak-tools, and I assume unity-tweak-tools and gnome-tweak-tools are not for KDE.

What is the way to create a cursor theme, based on an existing one, on Kubuntu ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution :
cursor files found in /usr/share/icons/breeze_cursors/cursors are .xmc files ("X11 mouse cursor files"). This type of file is handled by Gimp (2.8.22), so I had to save my file as a xmc file, then replace the /usr/share/icons/breeze_cursors/cursors/wait

Yet I do not understand why cursors images do not have extension, nor why they require a specific type of file